# Bluez BLE peripheral advertise custom characteristic with ADV data

Tags: bluez

Is there a sample app that allows advertising custom UUID and characteristics and with specific ADV data? Bluez has less documentation. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Which version of BlueZ do you have? With newer versions of BlueZ (e.g. 5.50) you can use bluetoothctl from the command line to do this as follows:-

```
#bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# menu advertise
[bluetooth]# uuids 0x1800 0x1801 0x1802
[bluetooth]# name MyDevice
[bluetooth]# data 0 01 02 03
[bluetooth]# back
[bluetooth]# advertise on
```

This allows you to set custom UUID, advertising data, and the advertising device name. You can dig through the BlueZ source to see how this is implemented using C.

I hope this helps.